# Load custom error message when jquery validation fails

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Hello I am working with an application that already has a few validation criterion, and loads hidden divs, specific to the error. Now I have a few dynamic rows to be populated, since I am not aware of what input type they would be, I am automating the process of validation using jquery's validation plugin.

Now I am unable to understand how I would be able display a block, when certain required 
element hasn't been filled. Presently I would check a condition such as

```
            if(country.length == 0 && state == 'xx')
            {
                go = false;
                document.getElementById('reqStateMsg').style.display = 'block';
            }
```

How would I do this in jQuery validate method?? Presently I am just loading all the elements with a class of required. But to display the error method, I must also add "***" which would load a generic method, that would work from my dynamic input elements, but I want to load my custom error div blocks for the static input elements.

Now I am only invoking the validate method now, I am not sure how would I add load the custom error divs from here.

```
$('#FormInfo').validate();
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you still writing `document.getElementById()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this a few different ways, first you can use the `errorContainer` option of jQuery validate():

```
$("#form1").validate({
   errorLabelContainer: "#error-container-form1 ul",
   wrapper: "li"
});
```

Along with HTML like this:

```
<form action="#" id="form1">
    <label for="Country">Country:</label>
    <input name="Country" title="Country is required" id="Country" class="required"/>
    <label for="State">State:</label>
    <input name="State" title="Please enter a state" id="State" class="required"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This would remove your need for a special `<div>` just for error messages.

---

However, if you need a `<div>` for error messages you could do something like this:

```
$("#form2").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        if (!$("form#form2").validate().element("#State2")) {
            $("div#error-container-form2").append($("div#state-error"));
            $("div#state-error").show();
        }
    }
});
```

and the following HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="form2">
    <label for="Country2">Country:</label>
    <input name="Country2" title="Country is required" id="Country2" class="required"/>
    <label for="State2">State:</label>
    <input name="State2" id="State2" class="required"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="error-container-form2"></div>

<div id="state-error" style="display:none">Please enter a State!</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JWTTZ/

jQuery validate is pretty flexible.  Make sure you read through the documentation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".erroclass").size() > 0) {
  $("#reqStateMsg").css("display", "block");
}
```

Comment: well that should be displayed only on error, so how would I know it is an error, in the validate method?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very jQuery like...

But this is:

```
$("#your-form-name").submit(function(){
 if(country.length != 0 && state != 'xx') {
  return true;
 }
 $("#reqStateMsg").fadeIn().fadeOut(5000); // slowly fadeout ;)
 return false;
});
```